# Javafx Text Property Binding

Tags: text, binding, properties, javafx, bind

I am struggling to bind some text specified coordinates so that when I resize the window the text follows suit.  Here is the portion of my code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < petrolStations.size() / 2; i++) {
    int j = i + 1;
    Text text1 = new Text(petrolStations.get(i), petrolStations.get(j), "1");
    text1.setFont(Font.font("Courier", FontWeight.BOLD, FontPosture.ITALIC, 10));
    text1.xProperty().bind(pane.widthProperty().divide(2));
    text1.yProperty().bind(pane.heightProperty().divide(2));
    pane.getChildren().add(text1);
```

To explain: petrolStations is an array of coordinates that are used to place a letter 1 on the page.

Here is the current output, as you can see all the 1's are combining in the middle rather than being in their specified coordinates.

[image]

EDIT:
I've changed the 1's to circles and managed to scale up the size but I still have the same problem, since all the coordinates are under 100 they sit up the top left, I need them to encompass the whole window and expand and separate as the window is resized larger.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < petrolStations.size() / 2; i++) {
        int j = i + 1;
        Circle circle1 = new Circle();
        circle1.setCenterX(petrolStations.get(i));
        circle1.setCenterY(petrolStations.get(j));
        circle1.setRadius(1);
        circle1.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
        circle1.setFill(Color.WHITE);
        circle1.setScaleX(3);
        circle1.setScaleY(3);
        pane.getChildren().add(circle1);
    }
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hapzc.png

Comment: That's because the bindings will run on initial stage show, and will override the values given in Text constructor. Are the petrolStations coordinates relative or absolute? How they change when window is resized? For example, if we assume the [5, 10] point is for window size 300x500, what will be the new point when the window size is 400x1000?

Comment: The points are absolute, but cant the scale change when the window is resized?

Comment: I may be confusing the issue, I can get all the "1"s to sit on there coords, which are all under 100, however they are all stuck up in the top left corner since the scale on which they sit is up to 100, which is rather small.  Can I increase the size of the scale when the window is resized?

Answer (score 0):

Why not take the ratio of x and y with respect to the width/height? Take a look at this:

```
    Pane pane = new Pane();
    Text text = new Text(250,250,"1");
    pane.getChildren().add(text);

    double width = 150;
    double height = 150;
    Scene scene = new Scene(pane, width, height);

    double x = 50; 
    double y = 50;

    double xRatio = x / width; //GET THE RATIO
    double yRatio = y / width; //GET THE RATIO

    text.xProperty().bind(pane.widthProperty().multiply(xRatio));
    text.yProperty().bind(pane.heightProperty().multiply(yRatio));

    stage.setTitle("Hello World!");
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
```

When I run this code, the initial state is:

[image]

Upon resizing:

[image]

Comment: This has helped me about half way there thank you.  But there are about 50 1s that need to be on the screen and they are bunching up on the one spot.